# how to change sector boundary?

Tags: virtualbox, parrot-os

I want to convert vmdk to dvi but i have a trouble

```
  VBoxManage convertfromraw --format VDI 'OWASP BWA-cl1.vmdk' OWASPBWA.vdi
  
  Converting from raw image file="OWASP BWA-cl1.vmdk" to file="OWASPBWA.vdi"...
  Creating dynamic image with size 780 bytes (1MB)...
  VBoxManage: error: VD: The given disk size 780 is not aligned on a sector boundary (512 bytes)
  VBoxManage: error: Error code VERR_VD_INVALID_SIZE at /home/vbox/vbox-6.1.32/src/VBox/Storage/VD.cpp(6242) in function int VDCreateBase(PVDISK, const char*, const char*, uint64_t, unsigned int, const char*, PCVDGEOMETRY, PCVDGEOMETRY, PCRTUUID, unsigned int, PVDINTERFACE, PVDINTERFACE)
```

3VBoxManage: error: Cannot create the disk image "OWASPBWA.vdi": VERR_VD_INVALID_SIZE

Comment: `convertfromraw` suggests that it expects to read either a "raw" partition, or a raw disk image created using a tool such as `dd`. By comparison `vmdk` is an "intelligent" container file format used for virtual disks, it is pretty far from being a "raw disk".

Answer (score 2):

The `convertfromraw` command in VirtualBox can't convert from VMDK files. As its name says, it only converts from "raw" image files (i.e. ones which aren't in *any* special format yet).

(Sector boundary isn't the problem; this error message shows up because `convertfromraw` just doesn't understand the input image format and thinks the virtual disk is smaller than it's supposed to be.)

VirtualBox should actually be able to use VMDK images directly – it doesn't require VDI.

Use the `qemu-img` command from QEMU to convert between VMDK and VDI (and other formats):

- `qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O vdi image.vmdk image.vdi`
- https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/convert-images.html

Comment: 'E: Unable to locate package qemu-utils' how to fix this?